# Adjusting Munin's accept timeout

Tags: timeout, munin

I have a Munin master that's contacting 5 nodes at the moment and I'm seeing one to two warnings like this in the munin-update.log.

```
[WARNING] Call to accept timed out.  Remaining workers: xyz;abc
```

Is there anyway to adjust the 'accept timeout' that the update workers abide by?

Answer (score 1):

in your plugin configuration file add

timeout 120

or on a per plugin basis in plugin-conf.d

[plugin_name]
timeout 120

There is more black magic going on, it seems the munin-update polls every 10 seconds and timeout after 2 minutes so any timeout > 2minutes on the plugin side has no effect. I'll check for munin-update timeout.

Seems like a long time but I do have issues where plugins take a very long time and can't find the root cause, the problem is on centOS when a plugin timeout it becomes orphan and takes 100% cpu :(

If you had this problem and found a solution I'm a taker...

--Gilles